# How to get a lable "New stories" which is in facebook on top of recyclerview in android

Tags: android, material-design, floating

This is a picture of facebook app,I'm trying to implement that **"New Stores"** part into my app.

Can some one suggest me how can i do that.
Is there any library to get this done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This library by Etienne Lawlor does exactly this, and is well documented which should make the whole thing super easy:

[QuickReturn](https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn)

Answer (score 1):

You could place a "New Stories" `ImageView` in your feed layout at the bottom(assuming the parent layout is RelativeLayout or FrameLayout) so that this `ImageView` would be at the top of `z-index` in comparison to other views. You can place this `ImageView` at a predefined fixed distance from top of the screen and centre it horizontally. By default, put it's visibility as `gone`.

Now, when you detect that you have some new data available to show, turn the visibility of this `ImageView` on, and set an `OnClickListener` which scrolls the list to the top. After that just set the visibility of the `ImageView` as `gone`.

Hope that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you could put an `ImageView` and `TextView` in your `layout` `setVisibility.GONE`. And run a network call to check if there new data on the server. if you gets new events in response than `setVisibility.VISIBLE`
and apply `clickListener` on the `imageView` to go to top of the page.